# how to write a loop to know the type of all columns in a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set with 12 variables and i want to know the data type of each variable at single time

```
   userid    tonumber      fromnumber  smssplits operator      
0  sbs1      919899980898     HITECH          1  VODAFONE           
1  sbs1      919899980898     HITECH          1  VODAFONE             
2  sbs1      919899980898     HITECH          1  VODAFONE             
3  sbs1      919899980898     HITECH          1  VODAFONE             
4  sbs1      919899980898     HITECH          1  VODAFONE            
5  sbs1      919899980898     HITECH          1  VODAFONE          
6  sbs1      919899980898     HITECH          1  VODAFONE
```

so for the above data i need to find out the names of the columns and datatype of each column at a time using loop

tried:

```
for i in data.columns:  
    print type(i)
```

Comment: Sorry are you looking for DSM's answer which is the same as this `for col in df:
    print(col, df[col].dtype)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this information via `df.dtypes`, and iterate over it using (e.g.) `iteritems`:

```
>>> df.dtypes
userid        object
tonumber       int64
fromnumber    object
smssplits      int64
operator      object
dtype: object
>>> for colname, coltype in df.dtypes.iteritems():
...     print(colname, coltype)
...     
userid object
tonumber int64
fromnumber object
smssplits int64
operator object
```